# Модальные окна + ютуб

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

Имеется модальное окно в котором есть видос с ютуба вставленный через iframe и кнопка закрывающая это модальное окно.Но есть баг,при закрытии этого модального окна видео продолжает играть в фоне.Как его останавливать вместе с закрытием??

HTML код модального окна:

```html
<div class="modWindow">
        <div class="win">
            <img src="" alt="">
            <iframe src="" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat molestias alias, earum pariatur dolores illo quod voluptates iure rem deleniti?
            </p>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" id="closeModWindow">Close</button>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Код открытия модального окна:

```js
videoList.onclick = function(e){
    let target = e.target.closest("div");

    if(target.className != 'preview') return;

    modalWindow.querySelector("iframe").style.display = 'flex';
    modalWindow.querySelector("img").style.display = 'none'; //скрывать img в случае,если модальное окно вызывается для видео
    modalWindow.querySelector("iframe").src = target.dataset.videoSrc;
    modalWindow.style.display = 'flex';
};
```

Код закрытия модального окна:

```js
buttonClose.onclick = function(){
    modalWindow.style.display = 'none';
};
```

Comment: вы не закрываете окно (не удаляете его со страницы) а просто скрываете его через display = 'none'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так должно работать:

```
 buttonClose.onclick = function(){
        modalWindow.querySelector("iframe").src = '';
        modalWindow.style.display = 'none';
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Для остановки видео не надо "выдумывать" какие-то методы... На дворе какой век?... правильно...  Используйте всю мощь `Javascript` :) Активируйте `API` добавив к `src`  `?enablejsapi=1` и вам будет доступно все!
Рабочий пример в `jsfiddle` - https://jsfiddle.net/ph7r5x39/

Вот рабочий пример:

```js
var customStopVideo = () => {
 var iframe = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
 Array.prototype.forEach.call(iframe, iframe => {
  iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
   event: 'command',
   func: 'stopVideo'
  }), '*');
 });
}



document.getElementById("closeModWindow").onclick = function () {
 customStopVideo();
};
```

```html
<div class="modWindow">
 <div class="win">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bnBX6YHgaeU?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat molestias alias, earum pariatur dolores illo quod voluptates iure rem deleniti?
  </p>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" id="closeModWindow">Close</button>

 </div>
</div>
```

ЗЫ тут плеер блокируется, по этой причине работу кода смотрим на `jsfiddle`